# message table schema - body TEXT or varchar

Tags: database-design, optimization, schema

I want to make a small social network. For messaging body which one is more suitable? VARCHAR or TEXT?
if VARCHAR how long is efficient?

Comment: Sow which DBMS are you using? Postgres?

Comment: Depends on the **concrete database** you're using.... MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server?  For SQL Server, `Text` and `NText` are **deprecated** and should **not** be used anymore

Answer (score 1):

To completely determine column type, I might suggest to do following:

1. Check possible data types in real world: *is it string, or number, or large text block, or date?*
2. Determine which operation types you would like to perform with the column: *for example, **barcode** has numeric format, but calculate sum or average of **barcode** isn't valid.*

You have selection of two types: `TEXT` or `VARCHAR`. If you would like to perform `FULLTEXT` search, then you have to use `TEXT`. For other cases `VARCHAR` acts almost same as `TEXT`.

*"Which of them to use?"* depends on subject area and is primarily opinion-based question. If you ask me, then I might suggest to use `VARCHAR` (if no fulltext search is planned) up to `VARCHAR(2000)`.

---

From [`MySQL.com`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html):

> In the following table, M represents the declared column length in
>   characters for nonbinary string types and bytes for binary string
>   types. L represents the actual length in bytes of a given string
>   value.
>
> *VARCHAR(M):* **L + 1** bytes if column values require 0 – 255 bytes, **L + 2** bytes if values may require more than 255 bytes.
>
> *TEXT:* **L + 2** bytes, where **L < 2^16**.

For small messages, storage space of which requires less than 255 bytes, `VARCHAR` will save some extra disk space.

---

*I'm supposing that you use MySQL RDBMS.*

Comment: thanks for your answer. You pointed to important issue. `VARCHAR(2000)` is fine however many people may only send _Hi how are you_ message to each other. which wastes a lot of storage. I dont want to use full text search on messages. Does using `TEXT` slows down my database significantly? and what is the advantage of `VARCHAR` over `TEXT`? i use relational model.

Comment: @meshiv I've updated.